# php preg_split text

Tags: php, preg-split

Hopefully a simple problem but cant find the solution anywhere.

If I want to take any charactors before the "v" how would I do it?

Example:

Chelsea v Aston Villa - Match Betting;

I cant take the first word as sometimes it is two words like:

Man Utd v Blackburn - Match Betting;

Any help gratefully appreciated

Thanks

Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = "Chelsea v Aston Villa - Match Betting;";
$str = explode(" v ", $str);
$str = $str[0];
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$text = 'abc def v ghi jkl';
list($left, $right) = explode(" v ", $text, 1);
echo $left, ' v ', $right;
```

Answer (score 0):

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Example here: http://ideone.com/nQLhV

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this:

```
$text = "Man Utd v Blackburn - Match Betting";
echo $first = array_pop(array_reverse(explode(" v ", $text))); // shows Man Utd
```

Comment: Exploding on `v` might fail if name contains `v`

Comment: thats wat he wants to do.... "If I want to take any charactors before the "v" how would I do it? "

Comment: Much too complex for a simple task.

Comment: well it depends on how you take it dude...!